The need for speech to speech software
Some people listen to people but are unable to figure out what they are saying, explaining / laying out, or requesting, due to the usage of specific patterns of intonation and spacing and pauses between words.
In order to deal with this, it would be nice to have software that listens, and, then, outputs in a manner that that receiver can understand, as programmed by the receiver.
The receiver must be able to program intonation and speech pauses, as timed, or, as appearing in the speech.
Ideally, the user could also press on an artificial intelligence button to generate speech summaries.
That would be ideal software.
Several people, including people with cognitive difficulties or accessibility impairments, are in severe need of this.
Ideally, the software could also be trained to present in a format understandable or cognizable by the other person by means of their argumentative patterns or cognizing patterns.
Has anything been done in this area?
